# Background image overlapping edges flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a background image as shown, it needs to overlap the edges as shown in the UI render and I'm not sure how best to go about it. I've tried cropping it and using `BoxFit.fill` but this just leads to a change in aspect ratio which I don't really want, especially on different sized screens. I'm thinking maybe having it overlap on the left and right by a fixed amount and then the size changes to accommodate that depending on the screen size but not really sure how to code that. I've played around with expanded widgets inside columns and all sorts like that but to no avail.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you made the image a bit wider, you can use `BoxFit.fitHeight` instead. Here's a sample fitting a landscape image to a portrait view.

https://codepen.io/digitaljoni/pen/rNeMzdG

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            image: NetworkImage(
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542362567-b07e54358753?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```